# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [App\Event]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm creating a view list for M-M relationship for Admin view. I want to display every user that has been registered for that particular events. And I'm pretty sure I called it wrong thats the reason why I getting this error. I'm not quite sure on how to fix it. I tried googling and I still don't find any solution yet. So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation name is `users` not `user`. Please check using below code

```
use DB;
use App\Event;
use App\User;

  public function show()
    {
        $events = Event::with('users')->get();
        return view('admin.event.user')->with('events', $events); 
    }
```